# use of \$ when assigning a value

Tags: bash

I'm aware there are other alternatives to achieve the same logic which represents by below code , but I'm particularly trying to understand below code.

Both a and b functions provide identical results. What is the advantage of using `\$ in ( eval $1=\$result )` ?

```
#$1 varible to assign result
function x {
  local result=12345
  eval $1=$result
}


#$1 varible to assign result
function y {
  local result=12345
  eval $1=\$result
}


x a
echo $a # 12345
x b
echo $b # 12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` means the evaluation of result is delayed and done by `eval` rather than evaluating result when creating the argument for `eval`.

The former (`x`) does:

```
a=12345
```

And the latter (`y`) does:

```
b=$result
```

For most use cases there is no difference. However, if your string has spaces in it, then you will notice a difference.

eg.

```
function x {
    result='1 2 3'
    eval $1=$result
}
x a
```

gives:

```
bash: 2: command not found
```

where as

```
function y {
    result='1 2 3'
    eval $1=\$result
}
y b
echo $b
```

gives:

```
1 2 3
```